# Napili template standard search event

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, customer-community, napili

Are there standard events to capture the search term entered and search button clicked in the standard Napili template so that I can get search term entered and build my own lightning component with search term entered ?

Please see attached screenshot .Basically the aim is to capture the standard lightning event thats been published when user clicked search term on the header and call an API with search term entered ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a js listener to the search term text box -- or search button -- to intercept and execute your own logic ? Doubt there are standard components to execute this custom behaviour.

Comment: how can i add a Js listener inside lightning container ?

Comment: On your button can you add a onclick="javascript:alert('test');" to test out ? Not sure if can or cant just suggesting sorry. Am also on mobile or would try myself first - sorry!

Comment: Button is not under my control ..

Comment: Ok does it have an id ?

Comment: It's not vf..its Napili community templste

Comment: If u inspect button via dev tools in browser the button will likely have a DOM id. This is what I'd be looking at to hook an event listener to

Comment: Ids can change in SFDC without notice.I don't want any hack here.

Comment: Understood. Good luck with it 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to get on a call with Salesforce Engineer to really understand this .This is what we concluded

We can create a design file for the lightning components and use the same merge values as other components use on the page .In this case i can simple go to the Search detail page and check the standard context variable

[image]

In the above screenshot I have variables like "{!searchString}" and "{!topicName}" .I will need a design file for these attributes and community admin needs to use the same strings so that my lightning component can access it .

Here is a blogpost i wrote on this topic with some detail insight

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2016/01/customizing-napili-template-of-sfdc-for.html