# Is there a way to customize or build on top of the Global Search Results component in the Napili template?

Tags: community, customer-community, napili, search, global-search

I was just wondering if there is a way to edit or build features on top of the Napili Community's Global Search Results Lightning Component. I'd like to add filters, change the layout, and control access to where results are linking. I'm not sure it's possible, but it would be cool if I could still use the Global Search functionality that already exists and just alter it.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible .You will need to build your own custom component for same but you can still use the variables that builder provides .

You can add the custom lightning components in the search page .The search page itself is editable .

Create a design file for your custom component like below

```
<design:component>
  <design:attribute name="search" label="Search Term" description="Please add Search Term" />
</design:component>
```

Check the design variables that you will need in below screen shot

[image]

In your custom component in a design variable use a search parameter like "{!searchString}

Then from there all you need is a custom component .Check the below blog link

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2016/01/customizing-napili-template-of-sfdc-for.html

Also check the [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105627/napili-template-standard-search-event) answer.